# Format Email Raw Source to Reuse Styling

Tags: html, email, html-email, nodemailer

I am trying to copy the source code of a 3rd party email provider I'm using to match their look and feel.

I am viewing the raw source, to format it I had to remove all the `=\n`s (the end value of a line because the raw source breaks it up), however I still can't seem to figure out what to do from there to copy the styling since I can't find a parser to correctly handle this email HTML. Any recommendations on formatting an email or just grabbing the styling of it?

PS: I'm using `nodemailer` for sending emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit of a pain, but here are the steps in visual studio code:

1. Remove all `=\n` ("=" followed by new line)
2. rename to an `.html` file if you haven't instead of `.eml`
3. replace all instances of `=3D"` with `="`
4. search for any more locations for `3D`, delete each one you can
5. Now you have good html which just needs to be formatted, I recommend using a formatter like https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html
6. You now have your template, use templated strings to insert variables as needed. Use this for the `html` value of `nodemailer`